# Edit Distance between the words comparing between two Strings

Tags: java, arrays

I have seen many resources from the internet but couldn't found the exact help. i am trying to figure out the edit distance between the two strings example:
String a = "put return between paragraph gioo";
String b = "put hello between line phone gio";
here I am always comparing with String a with the other string so here the edit distance should be 4.
I have done some code execution its comparing me with the each character in the string.

```
                           int len1 = row10.length();
                            int len2 = row01.length();
                            int[][] dp = new int[len1 + 1][len2 + 1];

                            for (int i = 0; i <= len1; i++) {
                                dp[i][0] = i;
                            }

                            for (int j = 0; j <= len2; j++) {
                                dp[0][j] = j;
                            }

                            for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
                                char c1 = row10.charAt(i);
                                for (int j = 0; j < len2; j++) {
                                    char c2 = row01.charAt(j);
                                    if (c1 == c2) {
                                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = dp[i][j];
                                    } else {
                                        int replace = dp[i][j] + 1;
                                        int insert = dp[i][j + 1] + 1;
                                        int delete = dp[i + 1][j] + 1;
                                        int min = replace > insert ? insert : replace;
                                        min = delete > min ? min : delete;
                                        dp[i + 1][j + 1] = min;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println(dp[len1][len2]);
```

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: the program which i have posted is comparing the two strings complete edit distance I want only word wise. Eg: String a = "hello elina", String b = "hello gordon". I need the editsance as only 1 but the program is giving me 7 with the white spaces. I just need the edit distance of words without white spaces.

Comment: I am using excel table column input it has large data so I cannot put all white spaces with empty strings

Comment: A basic outline of the solution would be to use `split` to divide each input into an array of words, then iterate through those words in exactly the same way as your existing logic iterates through the characters, but using the `equals` method of the `String` class instead of `==` to compare them.

Comment: @Juke, So you want to calculate the number of words before first mismatch of words? E.g. `Sent 1 = My name is XYZ. & Sent 2 = My name ABC` . Then the output should be 2. Am I getting it right?

Comment: @driftking9987 yes u r right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a sample function. It doesn't really take into the consideration of corner cases but it works. Also, do think about the case sensitivity of the words.

```
package test;

public class CalcWordDiff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String a = "My name is ABC.";
        String b = "My name xyz.";
        System.out.println("Edit distance will be : "+calcDistanceBetweenWords(a,b));
    }

    public static int calcDistanceBetweenWords(String first, String second)
    {
        int res = 0;
        String[] words_string_first = first.trim().split(" "); // By trim, I removed the Whitespaces if they exist
        String[] words_string_second = second.trim().split(" ");
        //Check the length of both the arrays
        System.out.println("Size of arrays first is : "+words_string_first.length);
        System.out.println("Size of arrays second is : "+words_string_second.length);
        int lowerWordSentSize = 0;
        if(words_string_first.length<=words_string_second.length)
        {
            lowerWordSentSize = words_string_first.length;
        }
        else
        {
            lowerWordSentSize = words_string_second.length;
        }
        //Now iterate through the array of lower size
        for(int i = 0; i< lowerWordSentSize; i++)
        {
            if(words_string_first[i].equals(words_string_second[i]))
            {
                //Do nothing, it means both the words are same
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Words mismatched at "+(i+1)+" th Position.");
                res = i; 
            }
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Comment: In the question comment, you mentioned something else. This code is in accordance to that.

Comment: Now I understand. The above code will work too, just subtract the output by the length. For example, `Sent 1 = My name is ABC XYZ and Sent 2 = My name POI` . Now the above code will return 2, but what you need is 3 because you would need the send 2 to read "MY name `is ABC XYZ`", so the edit distance is 3. In order to get that, just subtract the output by the length of bigger sentence. So it would be `5-2 = 3`, your desired output. Let me know if you get it.

Comment: It actually throws arrayIndexOutOfBound Exception I thik I have to catch the exception by res++ but its showing me wrong output

Comment: It worked I have surrounded it with try catch and used highestWordSentSize